Calling parent class methods using the implements keyword
Using extends and implements keyword in Dart. Trying to call methods of the base class from the child class using both extends and implements keyword.
void main() {
  Dog d = Dog();
  d.walking();

  Cat c = Cat();
  c.reproduction();
}
// parent class
class Mammal {
  void reproduction() {
    print("Mammals can mate");
  }
  void climb() {
    print("Mammals can also climb the mountain");
  }
}
// parent class
class Animal {
  void walking() {
    print("Animal is walking");
  }
  void eating() {
    print("Animal is eating");
  }
}
// child class
class Dog implements Animal, Mammal {
  void walking() {
    print("walking() - Dog is walking");
    eating();
    reproduction();
    print("class Dog--Implemented class calling the super class method--\n");
    super.climb();
  }
  void eating() {
    print("Eating() - Dog is eating");
  }
  void reproduction() {
    print("Reproduction() - Dogs like to mate in the spring season");
  }
} 
class Cat extends Mammal {
  void reproduction() {
    print("Cat's mate silently\n");
    print("class Cat--Extended class calling the super class method--");
    super.reproduction();
  }
}

Error msg:
23-Extends_Implements.dart:38:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'Dog' is missing implementations for these members:
 - Mammal.climb
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class Dog implements Animal, Mammal {
      ^^^
23-Extends_Implements.dart:21:8: Context: 'Mammal.climb' is defined here.
  void climb() {
       ^^^^^
23-Extends_Implements.dart:44:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'climb'.
    super.climb();

The problem I'm facing is: I am unable define a 2nd method in the parent class and call it from the child class using the implements or extends keyword.

Those are proper errors.  If you use implements, you are expected to provide concrete implementations of every property.  Any code in the class being implemented is ignored. If you had used "extends", then any non-overridden method would automatically be inherited from the parent class.  Maybe that's what you were trying for.


The super keyword cannot be used in a class that implements another
class.
It can only be used in classes that extend other classes, not in classes that implement interfaces

You can achieve like below.
   void main() {
      Dog d = Dog();
      d.walking();
    
      Cat c = Cat();
      c.reproduction();
    }
    
    // Parent class
    class Mammal {
      void reproduction() {
        print("Mammals can mate");
      }
    
      void climb() {
        print("Mammals can also climb the mountain");
      }
    }
    
    // Parent class
    class Animal {
      void walking() {
        print("Animal is walking");
      }
    
      void eating() {
        print("Animal is eating");
      }
    }
    
    // Child class
    class Dog extends Mammal implements Animal {
      @override
      void walking() {
        print("walking() - Dog is walking");
        eating();
        reproduction();
        print("class Dog--Implemented class calling the super class method--\n");
        climb();
      }
    
      @override
      void eating() {
        print("eating() - Dog is eating");
      }
    
      @override
      void reproduction() {
        print("reproduction() - Dogs like to mate in the spring season");
      }
    }
    
    class Cat extends Mammal {
      @override
      void reproduction() {
        print("Cat's mate silently\n");
        print("class Cat--Extended class calling the super class method--");
        super.reproduction();
      }
    }


how do invoke the method eating() from the implemented Animal class? Why are we extending Mammal and not Animal?
